# BPMN Engine for NodeJS similar to Activiti or jBPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, activiti, bpmn

I am looking for a standard BPMN compliant Business Process Management(BPM) Engine in the Javascript or NodeJS world comparable to Activiti or jBPM. Anybody has a suggestion ?

Thanks,

Comment: Your question in it's present state is an off-topic (read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic bullet #4). What is it that you need to do/solve? Client-side? Server-side? Execute the model? Show it to user? Let the user edit it?

Answer (score 20):

Have a look at [bpmn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bpmn) package at npm. It is a BPMN 2.0 execution engine for node.js.

Other interesting workflow engines are:

1. [workflow-4-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/workflow-4-node)
2. [turbine.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/turbine.js)

Another possible option is [Camunda](https://camunda.com/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Raoof.

The [bpmn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bpmn) looks interesting. It covers many aspects of BPMN, and it's Promise (async) based programming model is also really appealing. I am wondering why it is not yet very active and popular considering the recent adoption of Node.js into the enterprise and the fact that there is virtually no competition in that space. I am seeing a big scope for a full-fledged BPMN engine similar to [Activiti](http://activiti.org/) in Java, in the Node world, [bpmn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bpmn) team should take it more seriously.

Comment: Zeebe.io is a modern cloud-native BPMN workflow engine with first-class Node.js support.

Comment: BPMN is not managed any more and has lots of issues, any other good packages?

Comment: Have a look at Camunda:  https://camunda.com/

Answer (score 12):

try the bpmn-engine, https://github.com/paed01/bpmn-engine
I tried it in my project, absolutely perfect.

Comment: bpmn engine is relatively complex then original bpmn, having JS code in cdata becomes confusing